# Firefox keeps reverting to Yahoo on searches

Tags: windows-10, firefox

Why does Firefox keep reverting to Yahoo for search results when I search with DuckDuckGo? My OS is Windows 10, Firefox Quantum 57.0.4 (64-bit) browser is set for DuckDuckGo as the default search engine. Location is Germany.

Comment: for a while it was resetting to Yahoo - Mine has reverted to Bing twice , same OS/and firefox - I have my default as google -

Comment: My machine just put bing back after I  removed it from the list. I'm wondering if the sync between machines is doing this

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if there is a file "dsengine.cfg" in Mozilla Firefox folder...and if so, delete the file ALONG with "dsengine.js" inside C:/program files x86/mozilla firefox/default/pref folder.
Adaware was the culprit for my case.

Answer (score 0):

Give [Avast Browser Cleanup](https://www.avast.com/en-us/browser-cleanup) (Freeware) a try. This may be the result of a sneaky toolbar or adware that made it's way into your browser and/or settings. If this does not work, try removing the profile folder located in:

```
%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\%ProfileName% *
```

If you end up fixing this by deleting your browser profile, you *will* lose some personal changes you havemade to Firefox. I do not intend to be cryptic by stating *"some personal changes"*, but there are far too many variables to account for to give a definitive answer as to what could be lost.

** Mozilla Firefox profile folder names will vary per user/machine.*